# Get count when when new entry occur

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have the Dataframe with ID and Date I have to count the new entry in each column and the count column in the Dataframe.

```
ID Date
A   1
B   1
C   1
A   1
A   1
B   2
```

I have this type of Dataframe and I want to  add the column and count the record when they occur and update the value of the count and final Dataframe will me give as:

```
ID Date  count 
A   1     1
B   1     1
C   1     1
A   1     2
A   1     3
B   2     1
```

I have merged the two columns and try to count the occurrence of the value:

```
ID Date  merge_col 
A   1     A1
B   1     B1
C   1     C1
A   1     A1
A   1     A1
B   2     B1
```

Expected Dataframe

```
ID Date  count 
A   1     1
B   1     1
C   1     1
A   1     2
A   1     3
B   2     1
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need to `count` over the `window` on group of `ID` and `Date`

Below is code for it -

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
        ['A',   1],
        ['B',   1],
        ['C',   1],
        ['A',   1],
        ['A',   1],
        ['B',   2]
    ],
    ['ID', 'Date']
)
df.show()
+---+----+
| ID|Date|
+---+----+
|  A|   1|
|  B|   1|
|  C|   1|
|  A|   1|
|  A|   1|
|  B|   2|
+---+----+

#Import required Libraries
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as W
import sys

df.withColumn(
    "count",
    F.count(F.lit(1)).over(W.partitionBy(["ID", "Date"]).rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0))
).show()

+---+----+-----+
| ID|Date|count|
+---+----+-----+
|  B|   1|    1|
|  C|   1|    1|
|  A|   1|    1|
|  A|   1|    2|
|  A|   1|    3|
|  B|   2|    1|
+---+----+-----+
```

## order for `Id` & `Date` will be random